# How does haskell type constructor -> works

Tags: haskell

```
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = [x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs]
                    ++ sublists xs
```

In the above piece of code can someone please explain what exactly happens at `[x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs]` this line and what `<-` this type constructor exactly does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no type constructor here. This syntax is called a list comprehension. It is based on set comprehensions from mathematics. A list comprehension gives an expression to create elements of a list. In this particular case, the elements are created with the expression `x:sublist`. `sublist <- sublists xs` means that `sublist` takes the value of each element in the list generated by `sublists xs`.

If you want to see how this works in a specific example, you can use the substitution principle. The first step looks like this:

```
sublists [1, 2, 3]
    = [1:sublist | sublist <- sublists [2, 3]] ++ sublists [2, 3]
```

Now you need to evaluate `sublists [2, 3]` using the same idea. I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader. (Note that Haskell will actually evaluate this expression twice. However, doing so by hand is just busy work and a complete waste of time. Evaluating it once will be enough to learn what is happening here.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. Can you please explain this with an example.. as in if i do sublist [1,2,3] how is [1,2,3] [1,2] and [1,3] evalated..

Comment: @SAYALIKULKARNI I have shown the first step in how to evaluate this. I suggest that you work through the rest on your own. This is a great exercise that will help you better understand functional programming and recursion.